# How to use export-CSV when your json file contains key-VALUES pairs instead of key-value pair?

Tags: powershell, export-csv, convertfrom-json

I am using powershell to try and convert Json to csv. I have the bellow Json file that I would like to convert to CSV. But for some reason when I run my code bellow:

```
(Get-Content $pathToJsonFile -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json) | Select * | export-CSV $pathToOutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

I am getting this:

[image: hosts ips System.Object[] System.Object[]]

Here's how the json file looks like:

```
{
    "hosts": [
        "myserver01",
        "myserver02",
        "myserver03",
        "myserver04",
        "myserver05"
    ],
    "ips": [
        "10.100.0.10",
        "10.111.11.111",
        "10.122.2.22",
        "100.22.111.111",
        "10.111.222.333"
    ]
}
```

I want the result to look like this

[image]

Please help. I have looked into this for the past couple of hours. I am not really good with powershell. How to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You have two unrelated arrays in your JSON file. How would you like to connect the right host with the according ip? ... just because of their order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?  I assume the first host goes with the first ip and so on.

```
$a = cat file.json | convertfrom-json

0..($a.hosts.count-1) | 
foreach { [pscustomobject]@{hosts = $a.hosts[$_]; ips = $a.ips[$_]} } | 
convertto-csv


"hosts","ips"
"myserver01","10.100.0.10"
"myserver02","10.111.11.111"
"myserver03","10.122.2.22"
"myserver04","100.22.111.111"
"myserver05","10.111.222.333"
```